# Does this equation have an explicit solution?

Tags: differential-equations, functional-equations

For a positive constant $C$:
\begin{align}
y(x)+C\ln y(x)=f(x).
\end{align}

At least from specific $f(x)$, such as piece-wise linear function, is there an explicit solution for $y(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W-function: according to Maple, $y(x) = e^{-W(e^{f(x)})+f(x)}$.

Comment: Sorry, could you help solve the revised more general form? Thanks.

Comment: I got it. It can be transformed back, and then use your solution.